# resize only height using wp_get_image_editor

Tags: plugins, theme-development, images

I want to resize an image keeping its original width unchanged. I only want to resize the height to 300px. I am trying following, but it changes the width automatically. How can I keep it unchanged?

```
$width = NULL;
$height = 300;

$image = wp_get_image_editor( $_FILES['u_img']['tmp_name'] );
$image -> resize( $width, $height, true );
```

Comment: You realize that if you do that it will skew the aspect ratio, or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do?

Comment: ...unless you set the crop flag like you did in your example...

Answer (score 4):

You can get the original sizes of the image being uploaded:

```
list( $uploaded_width, $uploaded_height ) = getimagesize( $_FILES['u_img']['tmp_name'] );
```

Then you can use those values to size the image as you like:

```
$height = 300;
$image = wp_get_image_editor( $_FILES['u_img']['tmp_name'] );
$image->resize( $uploaded_width, $height, true );
```